# Angular material 2 SnackBar Doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design, angular-material

I'm currently developing a WebApp using Angular 2 with Material.
The problem is that since I've updated my packages, SnackBar doesn't work anymore.

Here is my code :

```
import { MdSnackBar } from '@angular/material';

export class HomeMembershipComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public snackBar: MdSnackBar) {
        this.snackBar.open('Félicitation votre compte a bien été créé', 'Ok', {
            duration: 3000
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the error I'm getting :

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this._appRef.attachView is not a function
```

Do you have any idea of what is going on ? It worked well before the npm update.

I know Angular material 2 is an ongoing topic but there are no raised issue on their Github

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs for snackbars and dialogboxes after updating material from 2.0.0-beta.1 to 2.0.0-beta.2. Update of angular2 modules should fix this problem.

Going from 2.2.1 to 2.4.0 resolved this issue for me.